# Problem with unwrapping on one face in UV Editing

Tags: uv

I have created a rectangular box mesh and removed the front face and applied solidify to create thickness to the sides and top.
I have successfully uv unwrapped an image texture to one side but when I unwrap on the other side (to apply the same image texture) it displays as a triangle instead of a rectangle. I have tried dissolving various edges without success.
What is causing this problem?  I have attached the blender file.
[image]

[image]

Comment: I don't know how you ended up with this triangle, 2 vertices are overlapping, just unwrap again?

Comment: Just about to step out of my house I will try that later. Thanks

Comment: {"Could it be that v3.1 isn't compatible with the version your created it with?"} — Right, the file was made with the 4.0.2 version. But now I've converted it to 3.1. You can download it again from my answer (I've updated the link). Though I recommend you to update your blender to 4.0.2. The new version is better in many ways. You can download it from [www.blender.org/download] (new version can open all old files, but old versions cannot open the files which are made or was edited in the newer versions)

Comment: {"another question relating to solidify which made the sides 'thinner' than the top and bottom"} —
I've checked "Solidify" modifier and "Solidify Faces" function – both give the even thickness. I suggest you've encountered the uneven thickness because of the scale was not applied to the object. Try to apply the object's scale first: In 'Object Mode' press [Ctrl + A] —> [Scale]. After that you can solidify the object properly.

Comment: Thanks Yaroslav.  I thought that I had applied Scale but perhaps I didn't as I started a new 'box' and the solidify worked correctly (as Blender v3.1 crashes when I attempt to loaf your 'fixed blender file'.  I intend to search Youtube for converting N-Gons as I think I remember seeing something once on that subject.    Thanks again for your help.

Comment: {"as Blender v3.1 crashes when I attempt to load your 'fixed blender file' [...]"} — Ok, it's definitely a good idea to get more information about N-Gones. Though I've re-uploaded the file. Now you can download it again from my answer – the updated file will work correctly with your version of blender. Nevertheless I highly recommend to update your blender to 4.0.2. The new version is better in many ways. You can download it from [www.blender.org/download] (note: the new version can open all old files, but older versions cannot open the files which are made or was edited in the newer versions)

Comment: Thanks again Yaroslov. I would love to update my version of Blender however an addon I use frequently (Microsoft Flight Simulator glTF extension) apparently won't work with versions above 3.3 which is annoying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You had a nasty N-Gon there. It was causing glitches.

I've replaced it with a quad and re-unwrapped.

Then adjusted the opposite side of the box correspondently (to both sides having the exact same geometry)

HERE:

[image]

---

***FIXED BLENDER FILE :**

[image]

Comment: Thanks Yaroslav.   I had to go out shopping and meet someone and have just arrived home. I was going to resort to rebuilding the 'box' but now I don't have to thanks to you.

Comment: [added later]  In fact I think that I may have created the box incorrect in the first place and may have removed the front and rear faces before adding solidify and then trying to add the rear face (selecting the edges and then F (fill) instead of just removing the front face. Which begs another question relating to solidify which made the sides 'thinner' than the top and bottom (which seemed to be 'hooked' to the length of each side). I looked for a method to force solidify to make all sides the same width and everything I tried didn't seem to fix that problem-  tried Mode and 'thickness'.

Comment: Sorry another one.  I cannot open the 'fixed' blender file. Could it be that v3.1 isn't compatible with the version your created it with?